# Listing prime numbers up to 2 billion using sieve's method in C

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I tried listing prime numbers up to 2 billion, using Sieve Eratosthenes method. Here is what I used!

The problem I am facing is, I am not able to go beyond 10 million numbers. When I tried, it says 'Segmentation Fault'. I searched in the Internet to find the cause. Some sites say, it is the memory allocation limitation of the compiler itself. Some say, it is a hardware limitation. I am using a 64-bit processor with 4GB of RAM installed. Please suggest me a way to list them out.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 1000000
long int mark[MAX] = {0};

int isone(){
   long int i;
   long int cnt = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < MAX ; i++){
      if(mark[i] == 1)
         cnt++;
   }
   if(cnt == MAX)
      return 1;
   else
      return 0;
}



int main(int argc,char* argv[]){
   long int list[MAX];
   long int s = 2;
   long int i;
   for(i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++){
      list[i] = s;
      s++;
   }
   s = 2;
   printf("\n");

   while(isone() == 0){
      for(i = 0 ; i < MAX ; i++){
         if((list[i] % s) == 0)
            mark[i] = 1;
      }
      printf(" %lu ",s);
      while(mark[++s - 2] != 0);
   }

   return 1;
}
```

Comment: Try `gdb`. It's a usefull tool.

Comment: Do you realise you are basically asking for 16 GB of memory with `long int mark[2e9]`?

Comment: You are not going to get 16 gigabytes of memory, especially not on the stack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`long int mark[1000000]` does stack allocation, which is not what you want for that amount of memory. try `long int *mark = malloc(sizeof(long int) * 1000000)` instead to allocate heap memory. This will get you beyond ~1Mil of array elements.

remember to `free` the memory, if you don't use it anymore. if yon don't know malloc or free, read the manpages (manuals) for the functions, available via `man 3 malloc` and `man 3 free` on any linux terminal. (alternatively you could just google `man malloc`)

EDIT: make that `calloc(1000000, sizeof(long int))` to have a 0-initialized array, which is probably better.

Additionally, you can use every element of your array as a bitmask, to be able to store one mark per bit, and not per sizeof(long int) bytes. I'd recommend using a fixed-width integer type, like `uint32_t` for the array elements and then setting the `(n % 32)`'th bit in the `(n / 32)`'th element of the array to 1 instead of just setting the nth element to 1.

you can set the nth bit of an integer `i` by using:

```
uint32_t i = 0;
i |= ((uint32_t) 1) << n
```

assuming you start counting at 0.

that makes your set operation on the uint32_t bitmask array for a number n:

```
mask[n / 32] |= ((uint32_t)1) << (n % 32)
```

that saves you >99% of memory for 32bit types. Have fun :D

Another, more advanced approach to use here is prime wheel factorization, which basically means that you declare 2,3 and 5 (and possibly even more) as prime beforehand, and use only numbers that are not divisible by one of these in your mask array. But that's a really advanced concept.

However, I have written a primesieve wich wheel factorization for 2 and 3 in C in about ~15 lines of code (also for projecteuler) so it is possible to implement this stuff efficiently ;)

Comment: +1, especially for bitmask suggestion. This should allow to generate up to 100 billion on 16 GB box

Comment: Even without the more complex bitmask approach, the allocated memory can be cut to 1/8 of what it was by just using `char *mark` instead of `long int *mark`, since it does not hold the actual numbers but just `0` or `1` marks.

Answer (score 2):

The most immediate improvement is to switch to bits representing the odd numbers. Thus to cover the `M=`2 billion numbers, or 1 billion odds, you need 1000/8 = 125 million bytes =~ 120 MB of memory (allocate them on heap, still, with the `calloc` function).

The bit at position `i` will represent the number `2*i+1`. Thus when marking the multiples of a prime `p`, i.e. `p^2, p^2+2p, ..., M`, we have `p^2=(2i+1)^2=4i^2+4i+1` represented by a bit at the position `j=(p^2-1)/2=2i(i+1)`, and next multiples of `p` above it at position increments of `p=2i+1`,

```
for( i=1; ; ++i )
  if( bit_not_set(i) )
  {
      p=i+i+1;
      k=(p-1)*(i+1);
      if( k > 1000000000) break;
      for( ; k<1000000000; k+=p)
         set_bit(k); // mark as composite
  }
// all bits i>0 where bit_not_set(i) holds, 
// represent prime numbers 2i+1
```

Next step is to switch to working in smaller **segments** that will fit in your cache size. This should speed things up. You will only need to reserve memory region for primes under the square root of 2 billion in value, i.e. 44721.

First, sieve this smaller region to find the primes there; then write these primes into a separate `int` array; then use this array of primes to sieve each segment, possibly printing the found primes to `stdout` or whatever.

Comment: Are you sure the segmentation can speed things up? Have you run a benchmark or something similar? I like the idea, would be good to see some numbers :)

Comment: @AndreasGrapentin no I didn't try it; it's the accepted wisdom AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, the segmentation will speed things up, if done properly; the trick is to set a segment size that fits in cache memory. See my response at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249378/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes for a description of a segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes.