# integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type when searching for large primes

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes

I am trying to find prime numbers between 1,000,000,000,000 and 1,000,000,100,000. My code is OK if the number of digits is 4 to 8, but if the digits are more than or equal to 12 i am getting:

1. warning: integer constant is too large for ‘long’ type
2. Floating point exception

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#define num 1000000100000
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  bool prime;
  long double sum = 0;
  for (long long int i=1000000000000; i<=num; i++)
  {
    prime = true;
    for(int j=2; j<=i/2; j++)
    {
      if(i%j == 0) prime = false;
    }
     if(prime) sum+=i;
  }
  cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Replace `long long int i=1000000000000`  with `long long int i=1000000000000LL` and `#define num 1000000100000` with `#define num 1000000100000LL` and `for(int j=2; j<=i/2; j++)` with `for(long long int j=2; j<=i/2; j++)`

Comment: ... and unless you have a darn good reason, they should also be unsigned.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long does it take to run this loop?

Comment: @40two Should be about pow(10,17) operations. More than 3.17 years is my rough guess.

Comment: @WhozCraig He has a good reason to do so: they are numerical values.

Comment: MY algorithm isn't efficient Because I am running loop for more than 10 thousand million times.Which result in consuming more time about 20 min.How can i reduce the time consumed?

Comment: @MohitJain Using `long long` here will delay the problem, but there are still numbers which are large enough that they will overflow.  (But of course, using floating point won't work at all.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Sorry I could not understand your point. My understanding is OP wants a number large and accurate that it can perform `%` operation without overflowing for numbers up to `1,000,000,100,000`

Comment: @MohitJain If `1000000100000` is guaranteed to be the largest number he will have to process, `long long` is fine.  My point was only that even with `long long`, there will be some upper limit.  (Although come to think of it, realistically, given his algorithm, it's likely that his machine will not last long enough to finish the calculations for anything which won't fit in a `long long`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Got your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to add all prime numbers in range mentioned by you.
I would strongly suggest [segmented sieve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249378/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes) for your purpose.

Or you can do a plain sieving. Take an array of size `100001` to store whether `100000000000 + i` is prime or not. (better if you can do with `100001 / 2` bits) to store only odd number `100000000001 + 2 * i` and sieve out all the odd multiples in range `3 to 1000001` and add the remaining numbers.

But still if you want to stick with your method, I would make a few suggestion to make it run in some practical time.

```
#include <iostream>
#define num 1000000100000LL  // make long long
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  bool prime;
  long double sum = 0;
  for (long long int i=1000000000001LL; i<=num; i += 2LL)  // Make long long, loop through only odd numbers as even numbers are not prime except 2
  {
    prime = true;
    for(int j=3; j<=1000001; j += 2) // Loop until sqrt(i) only, loop through odd numbers only
    {
      if(i%j == 0) {
        prime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
     if(prime) {
        cout << i << endl;
        sum+=i;
     }
  }
  cout<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use unsigned long long int i=1000000000000LL instead of long long int i=1000000000000LL.

Also you have to use the **j** also as unsigned long long int because the **i/2** might not fit in the **int j**.