# Time exceeded error on SPOJ

Tags: c, algorithm

Peter wants to generate some `prime numbers` for his **cryptosystem**. Help him! 
Your task is to **generate all prime numbers between two given numbers!**

**Input**

The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line `(t<=10)`. In each of the next t lines there are two numbers `m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000)` separated by a space.

**Output**

For every test case print all prime numbers `p` such that `m <= p <= n`, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

here is the link http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/

I came up with this solution but its showing time exceeded error, so how can i improve it?

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 int main()
    {
      int n,a,i,b;
      scanf("%d",&i); 
      while(i>0){
        scanf("%d",&a);
        scanf("%d",&b);
        while(a<=b){    
            for(n=2;n<=a;n++){
            if(a%n==0)break;
            }
            if(a==n){
            printf("%d\n",a);
            }
        a++;
        }
    i--;
    printf("\n");
}
return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Linking to a live site is not useful for future interest in this question.. please add a Fiddle..

Comment: @JF it ; "Linking to a live site" ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest fast way to calculate primes is to use the Sieve of Erastothenes. The algorithm is to:

```
1)Create a list of consecutive integers from 2 through n: (2, 3, 4, ..., n).
2)Initially, let p equal 2, the first prime number.
3)Starting from p, enumerate its multiples by counting to n in increments of p, and mark them in the list (these will be 2p, 3p, 4p, etc.; the p itself should not be marked).
4)Find the first number greater than p in the list that is not marked. If there was no such number, stop. Otherwise, let p now equal this new number (which is the next prime), and repeat from step 3.
```

For this problem you would need to use [Segmented Sieve of Erastothenes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249378/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes/10249801#10249801). Check the link for details.

SoE Algorithm from [wikipedia(Sieve of Erastothenes)](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQygQwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSieve_of_Eratosthenes%23Algorithm_description&ei=md6_U8y4Fs2KuATupoL4CA&usg=AFQjCNH4_KJuHBIzfPUZ1U2k9cvjys0laA&bvm=bv.70810081,d.c2E).

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply [sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to solve the problem in the given time constraints. Checking if each number is prime one by one will be way too slow.

EDIT: in fact the sieve should be segmented, not a full sieve of eratosthenes.

Comment: "m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000" - that's a wrong approach.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath not only that it is not a wrong approach but I've also solved the very same problem with this approach. Still maybe I need to mentioned that a [segmented sieve](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10249378/812912) should be used.