# Python prime number code giving runtime error(NZEC) on spoj

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, primes

I am trying to get an accepted answer for this question:http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/
It's nothing new, just wanting prime numbers to be generated between two given numbers. Eventually, I have coded the following. But spoj is giving me runtime-error(nzec), and I have no idea how it should be dealt with. I hope you can help me with it. Thanks in advance.

```
def is_prime(m,n):
    myList= []
    mySieve= [True] * (n+1)
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        if mySieve[i]:
            myList.append(i)
            for x in range(i*i,n+1,i):
                mySieve[x]= False
    for a in [y for y in myList if y>=m]:
        print(a)



t= input()
count = 0
while count <int(t):
    m, n = input().split()
    count +=1
    is_prime(int(m),int(n))
    if count == int(t):
        break
    print("\n")
```

Comment: @undefinedisnotafunction I am sorry I didn't mention that. It's Python 3.

Comment: If this is some output from an online test program, my first guess would be that your program either takes too long to run, so the tester aborts your program and says you've failed, or prints the wrong results, or doesn't follow the instructions in some other way.

Comment: Does the documentation on the test site says that "NZEC" means?

Comment: One last thing: It looks like that site has a forum specifically designed for people to ask questions like this. So… why not ask on that forum, where everyone knows about the site, instead of here?

Comment: @abarnert NZEC means non-zero exit code according to SPOJ. I know they have a forum but I have come here first as I thought I could get answers faster than there.

Comment: You should be using a segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes as in [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249378/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes/10249801#10249801](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249378/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes/10249801#10249801).

Comment: @abarnert NZEC means Non zero exit code (Code must return 0 on succesfull completion)

Comment: @AshwaniDausodia: The OP already answered that 4 months ago.

Comment: @abarnert oh i didn't see that also didn't realize that it was  asked 4 months ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the problem definition:

> In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

Looking at your code:

> mySieve= [True] * (n+1)

So, if `n` is `1000000000`, you're going to try to create a list of 1000000001 boolean values. That means you're asking Python to allocate storage for a billion pointers. On a 64-bit platform, that's 8GB—which is fine as far as Python's concerned, but might well throw your system into swap hell or get it killed by a limit or watchdog. On a 32-bit platform, that's 4GB—which will guarantee you a `MemoryError`.

The problem also explicitly has this warning:

> **Warning: large Input/Output data, be careful with certain languages**

So, if you want to implement it this way, you're going to have to come up with a more compact storage. For example, [`array.array('B', [True]) * (n+1)`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/array.html) will only take 1GB instead of 4 or 8. And you can make it even smaller (128MB) if you store it in bits instead of bytes, but that's not quite as trivial a change to code.

Comment: I am very new to python, and this piece of code was the only implementation of "sieve of eratosthenes" that I could code. But as your guide, I will try to do it in the way you've mentioned although I don't have any idea how to. Thanks for the fast answer, I'd better read some more about this.

Comment: @user2694307: I'm not suggesting any change to your sieve code. That _might_ turn out to be wrong, or too slow, or whatever, but until you can actually get past this problem, you won't find that out. All you have to do is change the `[True] * (n-1)` to something more compact, like the `array.array` expression I showed, and your code should just work with 1/8th the memory, which will either solve your problem or let you find the next one.

Comment: @user2694307: Also, I notice that the winning answer uses 256MB of memory, which implies that they aren't demanding that you use segmenting or any other more complicated technique to avoid linear memory usage, just demanding that you keep it under some limit like 2GB.

Answer (score 0):

Calculating prime numbers between two numbers is meaningless. You can only calculate prime numbers until a given number by using other primes you found before, then show only range you wanted.

Here is a python code and some calculated primes you can continue by using them:

```
bzr branch http://bzr.ceremcem.net/calc-primes
```

This code is somewhat trivial but is working correctly and tested well.