# Prime numbers between two large numbers?

Tags: c

I wanted to find the prime numbers between two 13 digit numbers (1,000,000,000,000 and 1,000,000,100,000) ... I used something like `unsigned long long` or `long long int` and `scanf` with `%llu` and `%lld` but that does not work. How can I do this? I use the code like this:

```
int main()
{
  long long int n1, n2, i;
  int flag, j;
  printf("Enter two numbers (intervals): ");
  scanf("%lld %lld", &n1, &n2);
  printf("Prime numbers between %lld and %lld are: ", n1, n2);
  for(i=n1+1; i<n2; ++i)
  {
      flag=0;
      for(j=2; j<=i/2; ++j)
      {
        if(i%j==0)
        {
          flag=1;
          break;
        }
      }
      if(flag==0)
        printf("%lld ",i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out the [segmented sieve of Eratosthenes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249378/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes).

Comment: What doesn't work? The algorithm or scanf?

Comment: Will sieve cover  13 digit numbers ??

Comment: You might want to include some newlines in some of the outputs.  It isn't needed in the prompt (first `printf()`); most systems will ensure that standard output is flushed before reading anything.  But the other print operations should include some newlines.  Your algorithm is pretty inefficient.  All else apart, 2 is the only even prime number.

Comment: Try `%Ld` instead of `%lld` for `long long int` with `scanf()`

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi Yes, see [these stats](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/goldbach/sieve_speed.pdf) from [this webpage](http://sweet.ua.pt/tos/software/prime_sieve.html).

Comment: I don't think your code will work for 13 digit numbers but code that you posted is working pefectly!! check here : http://ideone.com/MSUKXK

Comment: `int flag, j;` <--- this little guy overflows.

Comment: regarding this line: scanf("%lld %lld", &n1, &n2); 1) the prior prompt does not indicate the two numbers need to be entered with an intervening space, not an intervening newline. 2) the returned value from scanf() needs to be checked to assure that both numbers were successfully converted.

Comment: need to validate the inputs to assure that n1 is actually less than n2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`j` is an `int`, presumably a 32-bit type, while `i` is a `long long int`, presumably a 64-bit type. Since `i` is more than 2³², the value `i/2` is more than the maximum value of the `int` type, which is 2³¹-1. Therefore the comparison `j<=i/2` is always true, and the loop `for(j=2; j<=i/2; ++j)` never stops other than through the `break` inside the body. But this `break` is invoked only when `j` is a divisor of `i`, which never happens when `i` is prime.

If you change `j` to be a `long long int`, I think your program works, but it will take a very long time to go through the inner loop — `n1/2` iterations. A simple improvement is to stop at the square root of `i` instead of half of `i`. This alone makes the program run at a decent pace on my machine.

You should add `fflush(stdout);` after each `printf` call, otherwise the output is buffered until the program exits. Alternatively, first call `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` to turn out output buffering.

This naive algorithm can definitely be improved: it repeats a lot of computations. You can store information in memory to avoid making the same tests over and over again; this is a time/memory trade-off. The [sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is a fairly simple algorithm that takes the trade-off to the other extreme: it maintains a table of sqrt(n2) bits, where the kth entry indicates whether k is prime. That would be workable here. You can also look at the open source [BSD `primes` utility](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/games/primes/) to see how they do it.