# Segmented Sieve of eratosthenes algorithm

Tags: c, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am trying to solve "PRIME1"(http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/) on spoj.
A lot of people are saying that I should solve it using Segmented Sieve of eratosthenes. I understood Sieve of eratosthenes but How I can implement Segmented one? I've seen all most all the resources and couldn't understand properly.
This is the code I've written for Sieve of eratosthenes :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main()
{
    long long int i,n,j,m;
    _Bool a[10000];
    scanf(" %lld",&n);
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=1;
    }
    for(i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)
    {
        for(j=2;i*j<=n;j++)
        {
            a[i*j]=0;
        }
    }
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]==1)
            printf("%lld\n",i);
    }
  return 0;
}
```

From this, How can I implemet Segmented Sieve of eratosthenes. Please explain it in a beginner's perspective.

Comment: @pzaenger : boolean data type.

Comment: I know. But does this even compile? I mean, where do you get `_Bool` from? Because C does not know `_Bool`. And: is this C or C++? (I guess it is C)

Comment: Instead of creating a large array of arbitrary size, you should use `std::vector<bool>` or whatever bool type you are using, which can be dynamically sized.

Comment: @pzaenger: bool & _Bool are same. I have habit of writing it as _Bool.

Comment: This is what happens if you tag C code as C++

Comment: I explain the segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes at some length [elsewhere at Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249378/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes/10249801#10249801). Includes pseudocode but not C.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is very simple:

- Start from `k=2`
- Compute where you would fall in after entering the interval; this is simply `x=((m + k - 1)/k)*k`. For example for `m=12345` and `k=7` you get 12348 and that's the smallest multiple of 7 greater than or equal to `m`.
- Mark the spot associated to `x` as "taken" and keep adding `k` to `x` until you get past `n`
- Increment `k` and repeat until you get past `sqrt(n)`

You don't need to test all values for `k` but only prime numbers. For that you can use a normal sieve to compute all primes not bigger than `sqrt(n)` (note that `sqrt(1000000000) < 31623` is not a really big number and there are only 3401 primes in that range).

Pay attention to not "marking" `x` at the start of the inner loop if it happens to be equal to `k`; the minimum value to consider for `x` is `2*k`.

You can stop at `sqrt(n)` instead of `n` because if you have a composite number `t<n` with `t=p*q` with `p>1` and `q>1` then it must be either `p<sqrt(n)` or `q<sqrt(n)` and therefore the spot for `t` has already been marked when you stop at `k=sqrt(n)`.