# Sieve of Eratosthenes Given with Range

Tags: c++, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to generate a sequence of prime numbers starting from N to N_Max in C++. My approach is to use Sieve of Eratosthenes to generate these prime numbers:

```
void runEratosthenesSieve(int upperBound) {
      int upperBoundSquareRoot = (int)sqrt((double)upperBound);
      bool *isComposite = new bool[upperBound + 1];
      memset(isComposite, 0, sizeof(bool) * (upperBound + 1));
      for (int m = 2; m <= upperBoundSquareRoot; m++) {
            if (!isComposite[m]) {
                  cout << m << " ";
                  for (int k = m * m; k <= upperBound; k += m)
                        isComposite[k] = true;
            }
      }
      for (int m = upperBoundSquareRoot; m <= upperBound; m++)
            if (!isComposite[m])
                  cout << m << " ";
      delete [] isComposite;
}
```

However this function wastes memory by calculating prime numbers 1 to N. Is there a function that will run faster and take up less memory?

Comment: You might enjoy my response to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10249378/segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes), which generates only the primes on a given range.

Comment: Its in phyton, I will try to translate, but thanks anw!

Comment: It's actually not Python, but a kind of pseudocode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is determine if values up to `sqrt(N_max)` are prime or composite - as you are already doing.    Then loop from N to N_max and determine if each value is divisible by the primes found (between `2` and `sqrt(N_max)`).

That would only be a minor adjustment of your approach.

An aside:  rather than using floating point to compute the square root (i.e. `sqrt()`) , there are simple algorithms for computing the "integer square root"  (i.e.  given a value `M`, find the value `R` which is the largest integer such that `R*R <= M`).   Easily found using your favourite search engine.   The advantage is that it gets you away from nuances of floating point, and having to convert back to an integer.