# Erlang: Print a List of Prime Numbers between first parameter and second

Tags: list, erlang, primes

I'm new to Erlang and just had a question. **I've already looked here on StackOverflow and done a lot of Googling.**

I'm trying to write a function that takes two parameters and returns the prime numbers between them. My biggest issue is with Prime testing (checking if a number is prime). I fix the rest of the stuff later.

Here's the code I have so far:

`-module(ListPrime).
 -export([primeList/2]).`

`primeList(0, 0)->
   io:format("No prime numbers here ~s~n", [0]);`
`

`primeList(Start, Finish)->
   CheckPrime = Finish rem Start,
   if 
    Start =< Finish, CheckPrime == 1  -> primeList(Start, Finish-1)
   end.`

Basically what I'm trying to do is:

- Check if Finish is a prime number.
- If not, move on to the next number (Finish-1).
- Continue until the base case has been reached.

It compiles but it obviously doesn't do what I want it to do because *I don't know how to check if a number is prime*.

I know what the definition of a Prime Number is (a number that is only divisible by itself and 1) but the only thing that comes to mind to write when I think about that definition is:

`Finish rem Finish`

and line of code works for any number that is used. How do I check if a number is prime in Erlang? Thank you very much.

Comment: There is a discussion about this in SICP that translates readily to Erlang. https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-11.html#%_sec_1.2.6 Testing for primality is an active area of research.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10249801/448810).

Answer (score 0):

The code below will test if a number is prime. just call the function isPrime and it will return true or false.

```
-module(isPrime).
-export([isPrime/1]).

 isPrime(0)-> false;
 isPrime(1)-> false;
 isPrime(2)-> true;


isPrime(N)->
  ChPrime = N rem 2,
  if
    ChPrime == 1 -> false;
    ChPrime =:= 1 -> true
end.
```

Comment: This seems just to check divisibility by two, and knows the values of the test for a few numbers. The if statement with the two different equality operators makes no much sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

try this, I hope it workds fine, just call the function `prime` and it will return `true` of `false` :

```
divisors(N) ->
    [ X || X <- lists:seq(1,N), (N rem X)==0].
prime(N) when N == 0; N == 1 ->
    false;
prime(2) ->
    true;
prime(N) ->
    divisors(N) == [1,N].
```

Comment: This might work. It is simple, the clause for two seems to be not needed. There are faster algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
prime([X|_]) when X =< 1 -> error(not_a_prime);
prime([X|Ns]) -> [N || N <- Ns, N rem X /= 0].
```

Comment: This just seems to extract the elements from Ns which are not divisible by X.

Answer (score 0):

You need a caller function!
Just do it like this:

```
%% caller function
run(X, Y) ->
    prime(lists:seq(X, Y)).

%% prime function
prime([X|_]) when X =< 1 -> error(not_a_prime);
prime([X|Ns]) -> [N || N <- Ns, N rem X /= 0].
```

`lists:seq(X, Y) :=` creates a list between two numbers

Answer (score -1):

This may not be the most efficient way to set the function, but it works:

```
prime(2)->true;
prime(N)when N rem 2 =:= 0-> false;
prime(3)->true;
prime(Odd)->prime(Odd,3).

prime(N,I)when N rem I =:= 0->false;
prime(N,I)when I*I > N->true;
prime(N,I)->prime(N,I+2).

primes(Start,Finish)->[X|| X <- lists:seq(Start,Finish), prime(X)].
```