# Intitutive method to find prime numbers in a range

Tags: c++, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

While trying to find **prime numbers** in a range (see [problem description](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PRIME1/)), I came across the following code:

<sub>(Code taken from [**here**](https://turjachaudhuri.wordpress.com/2013/12/14/spoj-prime-1-segmented-sieve-of-eratosthenes/comment-page-1/#comment-64))</sub>

```
// For each prime in sqrt(N) we need to use it in the segmented sieve process.
for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
    p = myPrimes[i]; // Store the prime.
    s = M / p;
    s = s * p; // The closest number less than M that is composite number for this prime p.

    for (int j = s; j <= N; j = j + p) {
        if (j < M) continue; // Because composite numbers less than M are of no concern.

        /* j - M = index in the array primesNow, this is as max index allowed in the array
           is not N, it is DIFF_SIZE so we are storing the numbers offset from.
           while printing we will add M and print to get the actual number. */
        primesNow[j - M] = false;
    }
}

// In this loop the first prime numbers for example say 2, 3 are also set to false.
for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) { // Hence we need to print them in case they're in range.
    if (myPrimes[i] >= M && myPrimes[i] <= N) // Without this loop you will see that for a
                                              // range (1, 30), 2 & 3 doesn't get printed.
        cout << myPrimes[i] << endl;
}

// primesNow[] = false for all composite numbers, primes found by checking with true.
for (int i = 0; i < N - M + 1; ++i) {
    // i + M != 1 to ensure that for i = 0 and M = 1, 1 is not considered a prime number.
    if (primesNow[i] == true && (i + M) != 1)
        cout << i + M << endl; // Print our prime numbers in the range.
}
```

However, I didn't find this code intuitive and it was *not* easy to understand.

- Can someone explain the general idea behind the above algorithm?
- What alternative algorithms are there to mark non-prime numbers in a range?

Comment: The basic principle is simple; once you have found a prime, all multiples of that number are not primes.

Answer (score 0):

That's overly complicated. Let's start with a basic Sieve of Eratosthenes, in pseudocode, that outputs all the primes less than or equal to *n*:

```
function primes(n)
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n
        if sieve[p]
            output(p)
            for i from p*p to n step p
                sieve[p] := False
```

This function calls `output` on each prime *p*; `output` can print the primes, or sum the primes, or count them, or do whatever you want to do with them. The outer `for` loop considers each candidate prime in turn; The sieving occurs in the inner `for` loop where multiples of the current prime *p* are removed from the sieve.

Once you understand how that works, go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249801/448810) for a discussion of the segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes over a range.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the sieve on a bit level, it can provide a bit larger number of primes, and with the buffer, you could modify it to find for example the primes between 2 and 2^60 using 64 bit ints, by reusing the same buffer, while preserving the offsets of the primes already discovered. The following will use an array of integers.

**Declerations**

```
#include <math.h>         // sqrt(), the upper limit need to eliminate
#include <stdio.h>        // for printing, could use <iostream>
```

**Macros** to manipulate bit, the following will use 32bit ints

```
#define BIT_SET(d, n)   (d[n>>5]|=1<<(n-((n>>5)<<5)))      
#define BIT_GET(d, n)   (d[n>>5]&1<<(n-((n>>5)<<5)))
#define BIT_FLIP(d, n)  (d[n>>5]&=~(1<<(n-((n>>5)<<5))))

unsigned int n = 0x80000;   // the upper limit 1/2 mb, with 32 bits each 
                            // will get the 1st primes upto 16 mb    
int *data = new int[n];     // allocate
unsigned int r = n * 0x20;  // the actual number of bits avalible
```

**Could use zeros to save time** but, on (1) for prime, is a bit more intuitive

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    data[i] = 0xFFFFFFFF;

unsigned int seed = 2;           // the seed starts at 2  
unsigned int uLimit = sqrt(r);   // the upper limit for checking off the sieve

BIT_FLIP(data, 1);      // one is not prime
```

**Time to discover the primes** this took under a half second

```
// untill uLimit is reached
while(seed < uLimit) {
    // don't include itself when eliminating canidates
    for(int i=seed+seed;i<r;i+=seed) 
        BIT_FLIP(data, i);

    // find the next bit still active (set to 1), don't include the current seed
    for(int i=seed+1;i<r;i++) {
        if (BIT_GET(data, i)) {
            seed = i;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Now for the output** this will consume the most time

```
unsigned long bit_index = 0;      // the current bit
int w = 8;                        // the width of a column
unsigned pc = 0;                  // prime, count, to assist in creating columns

for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
    unsigned long long int b = 1;  // double width, so there is no overflow

    // if a bit is still set, include that as a result

    while(b < 0xFFFFFFFF) {
        if (data[i]&b) {
            printf("%8.u ", bit_index);
            if(((pc++) % w) == 0)
                putchar('\n');   // add a new row                
        }

        bit_index++;
        b<<=1;                       // multiply by 2, to check the next bit    
    }

}
```

**clean up**

```
delete [] data;
```