# Prime Generator(for Spoj solution)

Tags: python, algorithm, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I have several days struggling with this Prime Generator algorithm for SPOJ problem. The problem state to print at least 100000 primes from a number m,n with n<=1000000000 in 6 seconds. I have this implementation that print 100000 prime in  11.701067686080933 seconds. is it possible to beat the time restriction(6s) in Python.
I feel that I miss something in my segmented sieve function , cause I just implemented it how I understand the algorithm work, maybe a change can make it better.

Some Help would appreciated here.

```
def sieveOfErosthen(m):
    limit=m+1
    prime=[True]*limit

    for i in range(2,int(m**0.5)):
        if prime[i]:
            for x in range(i*i,limit,i):
                prime[x]=False
    return prime  

def segmentedSieve(m,n):
    limit= n+1
    segment=[True]*limit

    for j in range(2,int(n**0.5) ):
        if sieveOfErosthen(j):
            for b in range(j*(m//j),limit,j):
                if b >j:
                    segment[b]=False
    for v in range(m,limit):
        if segment[v]:
            print(v)
    return True
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly at it contains several syntax errors.

Comment: Please see my segmented sieve [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249801/448810).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is a disaster.  Let's begin with the most glaring error:

```
if sieveOfErosthen(j):
```

(This is particularly confusing as your original code didn't define this function but instead defined `EratosthenesSieve()` -- later editors of your post mapped one onto the other which I'm assuming is correct.) What does `sieveOfErosthen(j)` return?  It returns an array, so in the boolean context of `if`, this test is always `True`, as the array always contains at least one element if `j` is positive!

Change this to `if True:` and see that your output doesn't change.  What's left is a very inefficient sieve algorithm, which we can speed up in various ways:

```
def segmentedSieve(m, n):
    primes = []
    limit = n + 1
    segment = [True] * limit

    if limit > 0:
        segment[0] = False

        if limit > 1:
            segment[1] = False

    for j in range(2, int(limit**0.5) + 1):
        if segment[j]:
            for b in range(j * j, limit, j):
                segment[b] = False

    for v in range(m, limit):
        if segment[v]:
            primes.append(v)

    return primes
```

This code can easily find the first 100,000 primes in a fraction of a second, But ultimately, if `n <= 1000000000` (a billion) then we have to assume the worst case, i.e. the last 100,000 primes in 6 seconds for some suitable m in `segmentedSieve(m, 1000000000)` which will take this code minutes not seconds.

Finally, you didn't implement a *segmented sieve* -- you implemented a regular sieve and just skimmed off the requested range.  I recommend you read about [segmented sieves in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Segmented_sieve), or elsewhere, and start over if you need a segmented sieve.

Answer (score 0):

For solving this problem you have to use Segmented sieve. 
there are some good resources please check these
[geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segmented-sieve/)
[quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-segmented-sieve-of-Eratosthenes)

https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/54416/segmented-sieve
 https://github.com/calmhandtitan/algorepo/blob/master/numberTheory/sieve_fast.cpp