# How can I modify my prime sieve code to prevent memory errors?

Tags: python, python-2.7, out-of-memory, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

My python 2.7 code which has been coded based on Eratosthenes prime sieve, to find all the primes under a certain limit, gives a memory error when finding primes over billion. In my code, I simply used a list to store true/false values corresponding to each number(true when it is a prime, false otherwise). Below is my code,`

```
def primeSieve(limit):
   sieve = [True] * ((limit+1)/2)
   for i in range(3, int(limit**0.5)+1, 2):
      if sieve[i/2]:
        sieve[(i*i)/2::i] = [False] * ((limit-i*i-1)/(2*i)+1)
   return [2] + [2*i+1 for i in range(1, (limit+1)/2) if sieve[i]]

print primeSieve(100000000)
```

How can I modify my code to find primes over billion ? Thank you.

Comment: Are you using 32-bit or 64-bit version of Python 2.7?

Comment: The sieve of Eratosthenes isn't really suitable for numbers over a billion. The memory requirements are enormous, and in most cases it's far more efficient to use Miller-Rabin instead.

Comment: Also, how much RAM do you have installed, and how much is available on your system prior to running this program? A billion 32-bit integers is 4 GB.

Comment: @Matthew Hart, I am using 64 bit version

Comment: @Patrick87, I have installed a 4 GB RAM

Comment: Use a [segmented sieve](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249801/448810) to find larger primes.

Comment: Well 64-Bit python uses 64 bytes for an empty list and then 8 more for each element in it, using simply math a billion elements would need `(8*1000000000 + 64)/1024**3` GB of RAM, or 7.451GB, which you don't have

Comment: Start by looking at [Making Sieve of Eratosthenes more memory efficient in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62899578/5987).  I'm tempted to mark this one as a duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making Sieve of Eratosthenes more memory efficient in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62899578/making-sieve-of-eratosthenes-more-memory-efficient-in-python)

Comment: @Nick with virtual memory, running over your installed RAM won't make the program fail - it will just make it really really slow.  I don't dispute your memory requirement estimate though.