# How do I calculate all prime numbers with a really large max in the browser using JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, browser, vuejs2, primes

I am working on some of the typical katas for JS and I came across one that wanted all the primes for a really large number. I tried the [following in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jn0bg1kq/4/).

```
findPrimes(max){
   let dont = [], primes = [];
   for (var i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
     if (!dont[i]) {
       primes.push(i);
       for (var j = i; j <= max; j += i) dont[j] = true;
     }
   }
}
```

This works relatively good till about `this.findPrimes(51475143);`, however, if I try say... `this.findPrimes(851475143);` I get a sad face an the JS engine appears to crash. I know I could probably do straight V8 and squeeze a bit out and maybe even go toward a C-based node module but to keep things simple I would like to keep it in the browser if possible. If not and proof can be provided I will accept that answer.

Comment: Hrm, well, regardless of method, an array with 3,084,205 items will be a bit unwieldy... I don't think Javascript is the right tool for calculating huge amounts of data

Comment: You should use a [_segmented sieve_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249801/448810).

Comment: [primes-generator](https://github.com/vitaly-t/primes-generator) can you give you better performance, provided you are not trying to put all your values into memory at once.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're having is likely due to running out of memory, with your `dont` array being the culprit. Luckily, since it's just an array of booleans, you can do the same thing with a bit array, which will save some space.

JavaScript doesn't have any native bit array type, but you can simulate one by storing an array of 32-bit numbers and using bitwise operators to retrieve or set the desired bit. So something like:

```
class BitArray {
  constructor(len) {
    this.arr = Array(Math.ceil(len / 32)).fill(0)
  }

  set(i) {
    const j = Math.floor(i / 32)
    this.arr[j] = this.arr[j] | (1 << (i % 32))
  }

  get(i) {
    const j = Math.floor(i / 32)
    return (this.arr[j] & (1 << (i % 32))) && 1 || 0;
  }
}
```

Then, with that alone, you can run your snippet and get a result (although it takes a while):

```js
class BitArray {
  constructor(len) {
    this.arr = Array(Math.ceil(len / 32)).fill(0)
  }

  set(i) {
    const j = Math.floor(i / 32)
    this.arr[j] = this.arr[j] | (1 << (i % 32))
  }

  get(i) {
    const j = Math.floor(i / 32)
    return (this.arr[j] & (1 << (i % 32))) && 1 || 0;
  }
}

function findPrimes(max) {
  const dont = new BitArray(max)
  const primes = [];
  for (var i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
    if (!dont.get(i)) {
      primes.push(i);
      for (var j = i * 2; j <= max; j += i) dont.set(j);
    }
  }

  return primes;
}

const primes = findPrimes(851475143);
console.log("Done. Max Prime:", primes[primes.length - 1])
console.log("And last 10 primes:", primes.slice(-10))
```

However, in addition to that, you can do a few more optimizations to your sieve:

- You can start `j` at `i*i` instead of just `i`, since any number less than that will have a smaller prime than `i` as a factor already (and thus, will already have been set in `dont`).
- You really only need to check odd numbers as part of the sieve, so you can change the outer loop to increment by 2 each time (`i += 2` instead of `i++`), and then change the inner loop to increment by `i*2` instead of `i` (since `j + i*(odd)` is always even).

Using those, you can change your snippet to:

```js
class BitArray {
  constructor(len) {
    this.arr = Array(Math.ceil(len / 32)).fill(0)
  }

  set(i) {
    const j = Math.floor(i / 32)
    this.arr[j] = this.arr[j] | (1 << (i % 32))
  }

  get(i) {
    const j = Math.floor(i / 32)
    return (this.arr[j] & (1 << (i % 32))) && 1 || 0;
  }
}

function findPrimes(max) {
  const dont = new BitArray(max / 2)  // Only need half the memory, since we only check odds.
  const primes = [2];                 // We already know 2 is prime
  for (var i = 3; i <= max; i += 2) { // Start at 3, increment by 2, so only odds are checked.
    if (!dont.get((i-1)/2)) {         // The (i-1)/2 converts each odd to it's "halfway" number
      primes.push(i);
      for (var j = i*i; j <= max; j += i*2) dont.set((j-1)/2);
    }
  }

  return primes;
}

const primes = findPrimes(851475143);
console.log("Done. Max Prime:", primes[primes.length - 1])
console.log("And last 10 primes:", primes.slice(-10))
```

As you can see, you get the same result for the last 10 primes, and, at least anecdotally, it seems to run quite a bit faster.

Comment: I confirmed it was a memory limitation using node. When I run the same code there I see...

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory` So I think you are on the exact right track. Thanks for the great explanation.