# sieve upto 2 billion gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I am using this program to check a number if prime or not.

Use algorithm - Sieve :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
//#define _max    2000000001
#define _max    20000001
using namespace std;
bool sieve[_max];
void init()
{
    memset(sieve,true,sizeof(sieve));
    sieve[0]=sieve[1]=false;
    for(int i=2;i<_max;i+=2)
    {
        sieve[i]=false;
    }
}
void go_sieve(int n)
{
    n++;
    for(int i=3;i<n;i+=2)
    {
        if(sieve[i]==false)
            continue;
        for(int j=2*i;j<n;j+=i)
            sieve[j]=false;
    }
}
void print(int n)
{
    n++;
    printf("-------------\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(sieve[i])
            cout << i << " ";
    }
    printf("\n-------------\n");
}
int main()
{
    init();
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--)
    {
        int x;
        scanf("%d",&x);
        go_sieve(x);
        //print(x);
        if(sieve[x])
            printf("Prime\n");
        else
            printf("Not prime\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now it works upto `2e7` and pretty smoothly, but I want to check upto `2e9`, if I change my `_max` to `2000000001` it gives me `segmentation error` and exits with an error code.

**How can I resolve this problem ?**

I have tried a new approach with set :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
//#define _max    200001
//#define _max    20000001
#define _max    2000000001
using namespace std;
set<int>prime;
set<int>nprime;
void init()
{
    prime.insert(2);
}
void go_sieve()
{
    for(int i=3;i<_max;i+=2)
    {
        if(prime.find(i)==prime.end() && nprime.find(i)==nprime.end())
        {
            prime.insert(i);
            //cout << i << endl;
            for(int j=2*i;j<_max;j+=i)
                nprime.insert(j);
        }
        if(nprime.find(i)!=nprime.end())
            nprime.erase(nprime.find(i));
    }
}
void print()
{
    set<int> ::iterator itt;
    printf("-------------\n");
    for(itt=prime.begin();itt!=prime.end();itt++)
    {
        cout << *itt << " ";
    }
    printf("\n-------------\n");
}
int main()
{
    init();
    go_sieve();
    //print();
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--)
    {
        int x;
        scanf("%d",&x);
        if(prime.find(x)!=prime.end())
            printf("Prime\n");
        else
            printf("Not prime\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Target is to execute it within 512MB~1GB memory.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. What is your exact input?

Comment: The program uses a lot of memory for the array (probably 8G). Maybe your system can't handle that. How much memory do you have? Are over-commit allowed?

Comment: Running example https://ideone.com/KJshJI

Comment: OT: you should check that x is lower than _max

Comment: And when doyou get the crash? Before `main`? During `init()`? At some specific x value?

Comment: @4386427 Could you describe how you get 8G?

Comment: Some systems have a limit to the size possible for static allocations, have you tried using a std::vector instead of an array? You should also make sure you're compiling as 64 bit otherwise you'll be limited to at most 4gb of memory

Comment: @ThomasSablik i guess he's thinking the compiler is padding bool to 4 bytes, pretty sure it's only 1 byte on most compilers so only 2gb of memory

Comment: @ThomasSablik sizeof bool is implementation defined. So it may be 1 or 4 or ... My comment should have said: 2-8G but can't edit it now.

Comment: given the hideous use of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` he must be using gcc so bool is probably 1 byte

Comment: i have used set and added the code in the question, it think it can solve my memory problem which it has, but now the problem is time.. it even takes more than one minute to detect only `3,5`.. within time it gets faster and faster

Comment: you may want to try `std::bitset`

Comment: Most C++ run-time libraries provide a specialized implementation of std::vector<bool> that uses only 1 bit per element.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to enumerate large ranges of prime numbers, you should use a [segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10249801); it will be faster (due to caching effects) and use less memory.

If you only want to determine if one number is prime, or a few numbers, sieving is a horrible way to do it. Sieving should only be used when you are interested in an entire range of numbers. For *n* up to a billion, trial division is simple and probably fast enough. For larger numbers, a Miller-Rabin test or Baillie-Wagstaff test is probably better.

Comment: For integers less than 82 bits there are deterministic versions of Miller-Rabin.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this on my system. My guess is that this has to do with a system dependant limitation.

You declare `sieve` as a global array (static storage duration) and it's huge (i.e. 2000000001 * sizeof(bool) - could be 2-8G depending on sizeof bool). Maybe your system can't handle that.

Instead of a global array, try using dynamic allocation:

```
// bool sieve[_max]; comment out this
bool* sieve = NULL;

...
...

int main()
{
    sieve = (bool*)malloc(_max * sizeof *sieve);
    if (sieve == NULL)
    {
        // out of memory
        exit(1);
    }

    ...
```

That said:

Your code is C++ but your style is more C like.

In C++ you would probably use a `std::vector` instead. That would make everything much easier.

BTW: Also avoid globals. Instead define the vector (or dynamic array) in `main` and pass it by-reference to the functions.

Comment: My system is 512MB virtual machine, to optimize I have edited the code and used `set`, can you see agaian, please

Answer (score 0):

You probably hit some memory limit on your system which causes the segmentation fault.

However, you don't need such a big array. Using Sieve of Eratosthenes, you need to calculate numbers up to `x`. Instead of an array you can use `std::vector` and increase its size as you calculate more numbers. This should allow you to calculate some numbers, but with large numbers you will hit the memory limit again.

You could also use some algorithm which requires you to store fewer numbers. To determine whether `x` is prime, you only need to compare against prime numbers that are smaller than the square root of `x`. You don't have to store numbers that are not primes. With `x = 1e10`, you would only need to store [`5e8` numbers](https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html).

Here is some example with vector (probably not optimal):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>

std::vector<int> primes = {2};

void calculate(int x) {
    const int largest_prime = primes.back();
    if (largest_prime >= x) {
        // Already calculated
        return; 
    }
    for (size_t i = largest_prime + 1; i <= x; i++) {
        bool not_prime = false;
        for (size_t j = 0; j < primes.size(); j++) {
            if (i % primes[j] == 0) {
                not_prime = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!not_prime) {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}

bool check(int x) {
    calculate(x);
    return std::find(primes.begin(), primes.end(), x) != primes.end();
}

int main() {
    std::cout << check(15) << std::endl;
    std::cout << check(256699) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: yes, can you suggest me some better approach and I have edited the code and updated the question, but memory is not a problem time is. can you help me with it ?

Comment: @Danial I added an example using vector.